# Add leading and trailing constant to a ContentView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

Currently, I have this:

[image]

I want the width of my red ContentView not 100%, I want a leading and trailing space.

I tried to set leading and trailing constants of my red ContentView which resulted in horizontal scrolling. I tried to disable horizontal scrolling, which resulted in a fixed ContentView with leading space to my UIScrollView.

How can I define values for trailing and leading constants on my ContentView, without the unwanted behaviour (horizontal scrolling)?

Comment: Could you please show the code of how you're currently setting up the constraints? Or if it's a storyboard/XIB, then a screenshot with the relevant parts highlighted will do.

Comment: There are several ways to do this... but, as Vadim said, we need to see how you are currently setting up your constraints - for both the scrollView itself as well as for your red "ContentView"

Answer (score 0):

You want to take advantage of the scroll view's `Content Layout Guide` and `Frame Layout Guide`.

Constrain your "ContentView" to the `Content Layout Guide` to control the "scrollable size" and constrain it to the `Frame Layout Guide` to control ***its*** size.

So, for example, if you want 20-points of "padding" on left and right, constrain its Leading to the `Content Layout Guide` Leading with a Constant of 20, and constraint its Width to the `Frame Layout Guide` with a constant of **minus 40** (20 points on each side).

Here's how it can look if you're doing this in Storyboard:

[image]

change the Height constraint on the ContentView from 120 to 1200 to see the vertical scrolling.

Here's the source for that storyboard so you can inspect it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="Y6W-OH-hqX">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="s0d-6b-0kx">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Y6W-OH-hqX" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5EZ-qb-Rvc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="gbkg" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kGy-CW-5oZ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="440"/>
                            </imageView>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="f6w-Hj-SnQ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="440"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bKG-7C-UV8" userLabel="ContentView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="240" height="120"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Your Content View" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5vI-Ro-IQh">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="224" height="24"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="20"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="5vI-Ro-IQh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="SOR-6B-qUy"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="5vI-Ro-IQh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="bKG-7C-UV8" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="Tdy-3P-f8D"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="5vI-Ro-IQh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="bKG-7C-UV8" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="V5A-6U-nMX"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="120" id="egx-Ye-Pn6"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bKG-7C-UV8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ds4-RC-JaM" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="0Gd-qA-Ieg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bKG-7C-UV8" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ds4-RC-JaM" secondAttribute="trailing" id="WGf-cI-cwg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bKG-7C-UV8" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="ds4-RC-JaM" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-20" id="hkb-0t-zAy"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bKG-7C-UV8" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="pcX-Se-Do0" secondAttribute="width" constant="-40" id="ndP-Ww-TIg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bKG-7C-UV8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ds4-RC-JaM" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="xbu-qJ-MLf"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="ds4-RC-JaM"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="pcX-Se-Do0"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vDu-zF-Fre"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="f6w-Hj-SnQ" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="INT-yJ-xuH"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="QF2-gZ-vye"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="f6w-Hj-SnQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="top" id="S8N-mU-Qc2"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="f6w-Hj-SnQ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Uv9-tZ-0tY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="YQh-qf-dC6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vDu-zF-Fre" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="ZCH-4J-Gvo"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vDu-zF-Fre" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="eAS-mf-ueb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="f6w-Hj-SnQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kGy-CW-5oZ" secondAttribute="leading" id="gvC-t3-aUK"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ief-a0-LHa" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="13.125" y="138.75"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="gbkg" width="667" height="1200"/>
        <systemColor name="systemRedColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.23137254901960785" blue="0.18823529411764706" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

And here's how you could do it via code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let contentView = UIView()
    let contentLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let bkgImage = UIImage(named: "gbkg") else { return }

        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        // background image view
        let bkgImageView = UIImageView()
        bkgImageView.image = bkgImage
        
        // create the scroll view
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        // label preoperties
        contentLabel.textAlignment = .center
        contentLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        contentLabel.textColor = .white
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.text = "Your Content View"
        
        // add label to contentView
        contentView.addSubview(contentLabel)
        
        // content view properties
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        
        // add content view to scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        // we'll use auto-layout for all views
        [bkgImageView, scrollView, contentView, contentLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add views to main view
        view.addSubview(bkgImageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // so we can do less typing in constraints
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // inset background image view 20-points on all 4 sides
            bkgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            bkgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            bkgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            bkgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // constrain scroll view to background image view
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgImageView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain content view to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
            //  top/leading/bottom with 20-points "padding"
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // we can leave trailing at 0.0
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain content view width to scroll view's Frame Layout Guide
            //  minus 40-points (20 on each side)
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // constrain label near top of content view
            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // content view height will probably be determined by your UI elements,
            //  but for this example we'll use an explicit height of 120
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            
            // to see the vertical scrolling, use this height instead
            //contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set up a width constraint for your scroll view. For example, if you want to have its width the same as the root view's width:

`scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true`

This way, the layout system knows that the scroll view should not grow horizontally.